# What is the meaning of the term "direction along a level curve g(x,y) = c"?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I am studying the topic of Lagrange multiplier and I'm at the point of learning why the method is true.

Provided that we want to minimize/maximize function $f(x,y)$ subject to the constrain of function $g(x,y) = c$.

There is a statement in the proof "At constrained min/max point, in any direction along the level curve $g(x,y) = c$, the rate of change of function $f(x,y)$ must be $0$"

Could you please explain me what does **"direction along the level curve $g(x,y) = c$"** really mean ? Can this term be understood as the direction of the tangent vector to the level curve $g(x,y) = c$ ?

The reason I ask this question is that, say, if we have $g(x,y) = c = 3 = x^2+y^2$ which is a circle, then innocently, I imagine the "direction along this curve" is an "arc" but it sounds not true.

Thank you very much for the clarification!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is the direction of the tangent at a point. You don't consider an arc because a vector represents a single direction at a single point. In other words, it is the *instantaneous* direction when you move along the curve.

Note that a smooth curved can be closely approximated as a sequence of line segments.